# Banach Fixed point theorem for ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

I want to prove the existence and unicity of solution of the differential equation $y'=-x^4y^3+\exp(-y^3)$ over $R=\{(x,y), 0\leq x\leq \frac12, |y|\leq 1\}$ using Banach fixed point. My question is how to choose the complete normed space ?
I know that the operator is $T: E\to E$ defined by $Ty(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x -s^4y^3(s)+\exp(-y^3(s)) ds$.
Can I choose $E=C([0,\frac12],[-1,1]),||.||_{\infty})$?

Comment: You will need to check if you have $\|Ty_1 - Ty_2\|\le C\|y_1-y_2\|$ for all $y_1, y_2\in E$ for some $0<C<1$

Comment: but what is the norm that i must take ? is $||Ty_1-Ty_2||=\sup_{x\in[0,\frac12]}|Ty_1(x)-Ty_2(x)|$ ?

Comment: Yes. Also, you need to check $T$ maps $E$ into $E$.